# Typescript + C# + Angular - Response does not match configured parameter

Tags: c#, angularjs, git, typescript

I've inherited an app from a former developer and I have pretty much exhausted all of my debugging abilities. This app is my first exposure to Typescript, so I'm feeling a little lost there as well. I also cannot find anything relating to this on StackOverflow that's been posted, so here's my problem:

I have an entity named "Task", whose definition in C# is as follows:

```
public class Task : ModelBase
{
    public Task()
    {
        FiscalYears = new List<TaskFy>(28);
        Flags = new List<TaskFlags>();
    }

    [Required, AuditField("Project", typeof(Project))]
    public Guid Project_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public Guid ScenarioId { get; set; }

    [AuditField("Active Status")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "A Task # must be alphanumeric.")]
    [Required, MaxLength(4), AuditField("Task Name"), AuditDisplay]
    public string TaskName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100), AuditField("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [AuditField("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [AuditField("ATO", typeof(Dropdown))]
    public Guid TaskAto_Ident { get; set; }
    public virtual Dropdown Ato { get; set; }

    [AuditField("DTO", typeof(Dropdown))]
    public Guid? DtoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dropdown Dto { get; set; }

    [AuditField("Performer", typeof(Performer))]
    public Guid Performer_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Performer Performer { get; set; }

    //<snip, several string fields here>

    public virtual List<TaskFy> FiscalYears { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Workpackage> Workpackages { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TaskFlags> Flags { get; set; }
}
```

When a task is requested, the task being returned is not null, it is in fact a perfectly valid task (confirmed through debugging). I also have the definition in Typescript here:

```
export interface ITask extends ng.resource.IResource<ITask> {
    id: string;
    projectId: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    taskName: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    ato: IDropdown;
    atoId: string;
    dto: IDropdown;
    dtoId: string;
    performerId: string;
    performer: IPerformer;
    //<snip, same string fields here>
    fiscalYears?: ITaskFy[];
}
```

taskCtrl.ts is as follows:

```
export default class TasksCtrl {
static $controllerAs = 'p';
private isEditing: boolean;
private taskId: string;
private item: ITask;
private children: IByFlagsResult[];
private flags: ITaskFlags;
private objective: ITaskObjective;
private tso: IPoc;
private poc: ITaskPerformingOrg;
private fyStartYear: number;

static $inject = ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', 'Task', 'TaskFlags', 'TaskObjective',
    'TaskPerformingOrg', 'Toast', 'Login', 'KeyGen', 'fyStartYear', 'taskInfo', 'dropdowns'];
constructor(private $stateParams: ITaskParams, private $state: ng.ui.IStateService,
    private $modal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService, private task: ITaskResource,
    private taskFlags: ITaskFlagsResource, private taskObjective: ITaskObjectiveResource,
    private taskPerformingOrg: ITaskPerformingOrgResource, private toast: IToast,
    private login: ILogin, private keygen: IKeyGen,
    fyStartYear: number, taskInfo: ITaskResolveResults, private dropdowns: any) {

    this.item = taskInfo.task;
    this.children = this.keygen.convertTreeToLinkElements(taskInfo.children, 'workpackage');
    this.flags = taskInfo.flags;
    this.objective = taskInfo.objectives;
    this.tso = taskInfo.tso;
    this.poc = taskInfo.poc;
    this.isEditing = taskInfo.isEditing;
    this.taskId = this.item.id;
    this.fyStartYear = fyStartYear;
}
//<snip, other methods here>
```

Here's the rub - I have two versions of this project. There's the old repo and the new repo (old repo was mashed together with a Java app, was too cumbersome in one repo). If I try to run the new repo version, then I end up getting

```
Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: {3} {4})
```

in the console when I try to view a task. If I open the old repo **while the new repo code is running** everything just starts working, but the changes that I've made (to the html) don't display. This change persists until I close the new repo in Visual Studio.

A second error accompanies the first in the console:

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'task' of undefined or null reference
```

Pointing at the line

```
this.flags = taskInfo.flags;
```

Debugging this shows that taskInfo is itself null. This is likely a consequence of the above error, but I thought it could be helpful to mention.

If you need any further information or code, please let me know.

Thank you for looking!

EDIT:

I have narrowed my problem down to the following block of Typescript:

```
if ($stateParams.taskId) {
            return task.getByName({
                id: $stateParams.taskId,
                projectName: $stateParams.projectId,
                peName: $stateParams.peId,
                pcName: $stateParams.pcId,
                scenarioId: login.scenario.id
            }).$promise.then((retrievedTask: ITask) => {
                var flags = task.getFlags({ id: retrievedTask.id }).$promise.catch(() => []);
                var objectives = taskObjective.query({ id: retrievedTask.id }).$promise.catch(() => {
                    return new taskObjective({ taskId: retrievedTask.id }).$save();
                });
                var pOrgs = taskPerformingOrg.getByTask({ id: retrievedTask.id }).$promise.catch(() => {
                    return new taskPerformingOrg({ taskId: retrievedTask.id }).$save();
                });
                var tso = project.get({ id: retrievedTask.projectId }).$promise.then((project: IProject) => {
                    return poc.query({ id: project.pocId }).$promise.catch(() => {});
                });
                var children = workpackage.getByParent({ parentId: retrievedTask.id, scenarioId: login.scenario.id }).$promise.catch(() => [{"error":"Error"}]);

                return $q.all([flags, objectives, pOrgs, tso, children]).then(
                    (<any>_).spread((flags: ITaskFlags, objectives: ITaskObjective,
                        poc: ITaskPerformingOrg, tso: IPoc, children: ITreeNode[]) => {

                        visit.createVisit({ itemType: ReportLevel.Task, itemId: retrievedTask.id, scenarioId: login.scenario.id });

                        angular.extend(promiseResults, {
                            isEditing: true,
                            task: retrievedTask,
                            children: children,
                            flags: flags,
                            objectives: objectives,
                            poc: poc,
                            tso: tso
                        });

                        return promiseResults;
                    })
                    ).catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
            }).catch(() => {
                promiseResults.task = <ITask> { id: '404' };
                return promiseResults;
            });
```

Specifically, the line that is failing seems to be:

```
return $q.all([flags, objectives, pOrgs, tso, children]).then(
                    (<any>_).spread((flags: ITaskFlags, objectives: ITaskObjective,
                        poc: ITaskPerformingOrg, tso: IPoc, children: ITreeNode[]) =>
```

Comment: Your dependencies come to time as something that may have changed, NuGet dependencies or others. It will be hard to help you there. However, I've seen this error before. It is usually because 1) your WebAPI endpoint is returning IEnumerable instead of an object or 2) your routes are being hit incorrectly due to bad/missing parameters being passed in the request or bad route configuration. Debug the exact request with Fiddler, see which endpoint (WebAPI controller function) it's hitting, and verify its not returning IEnumerable. If it is, you can debug from there.

Comment: WebAPI controller function is being hit appropriately, and is returning a single Task. The dependency angle is interesting, I have the old code base and (if I knew where to look and how to do it) could probably restore to those versions.

Comment: Then the response body should be contained in {...} and not [{...}]. Angular's $resource service is detecting [] is what this error means, I believe. Could be wrong, I'm not sure how TypeScript changes things.

Comment: Response body opens and closes with {...}, but contains several [{...}] within it. This same response is generated with the old code base, and appears to be working correctly. Edit: Do you happen to know of any way to get a list of all dependencies (NuGet or otherwise)? I'm going to try to take a look at those next.

Comment: Copied over all dependencies, no dice. Any ideas as to where to proceed from here?

Comment: Not really. What $q.all() is doing is waiting for the responses of all of those Ajax calls to come back before proceeding. Any one of the $resource calls could be causing this error. Very likely, just knowing convention, in that block you added anything that has $promise hanging off the end is an Ajax call. You might want to do the same analysis you did on the task on those endpoints as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was. It turns out that I removed the Dto field and DtoId fields from the C# entities, but didn't remove them from the Typescript definition. If you are having the same issue, I highly recommend looking line by line at your entity definitions and trying to determine if something is missing.